# How to setup an alias in IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, windows, cname-record, hostname

I'm a SharePoint developer, so please, bear with me here and I'll provide more information as needed since I'm not sure what I need to specify here!

I'm trying to setup an alias in IIS. I have a hostname for our intranet, `http://vshoprspfe:27366` but I want a cname so that `http://ccq` will point here instead and any URL's within the page start with `http://ccq`. What should I be researching to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to set up a binding for the alias.  Assuming you already have a CNAME in DNS

- Go into IIS Manager
- Right-click your site and choose Edit Bindings
- Add a new http site binding with the cname in the Host Name box

That said, if you want a URL that does not include the 27366 port number then you will either need to change the site to port 80 or set up a redirect.  It's not 100% clear to me if that's what you want, though.

Comment: For the best user experience, you'll probably want to use URL Rewrite on http (tcp80) and https (tcp443) to redirect requests for ccq to the alternate port.